# Facebook SDK 3.6 for iOS error 2 on device

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, ios6

Facebook login works properly on iOS simulator, but it doesn't work on device (iPhone 4). As far as it works on simulator, I think facebookId, permissions, .... are set up ok.

```
NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email",nil];

[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
    [self sessionStateChanged:session state:status error:error];
}];
```

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: Have you disabled sandbox mode?

Comment: Yes. It works on simulator

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!!

I checked SessionLoginSample in FacebookSDK and I found a solution.

I had to change above code to this one:

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
if (!appDelegate.session.isOpen || appDelegate.session.state != FBSessionStateCreated) {
    // Create a new, logged out session.
    appDelegate.session = [[FBSession alloc] init];
}

// if the session isn't open, let's open it now and present the login UX to the user
[appDelegate.session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                 FBSessionState status, 
                                                 NSError *error) {
    // and here we make sure to update our UX according to the new session state
    [self sessionStateChanged:session state:status error:error];
}];
```

I added a property in MyAppDelegate.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) FBSession *session;
```

and change a method in MyAppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication: (NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
//  return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication withSession:self.session];

}
```

It works fine now :)